# calculate the mean for a column of a dataframe in R ignoring NA and 0 values

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a data frame in r that has a date_time column( every 10 minutes one observation) and another column for lux ..I want to calculate average lux for entire column ignoring NA and 0 values.

and also I want to calculate average daily lux..

how can I do this ?

Comment: for the second part I used 
meandailylux<-aggregate(list(avelux = df10$lux), 
                   list(dailylux = cut(df10$date_time, "24 hour")), 
                   mean,na.rm = TRUE)                                                                                                       but I don't know how can I ignore zeros

Answer (score 0):

without a sample dataset I can only help by providing a working example from another dataset. Copy paste the content below, and name the file: `daily-min-temperatures.txt`.

```
"Date","Temp"
"1981-01-10",20.0
"1981-01-11",0
"1981-01-12",13.3
"1981-01-13",NA
"1981-01-14",21.5
"1981-02-09",25.0
"1981-02-10",0
"1981-02-11",13.7
"1981-02-12",NA
"1981-03-08",16.3
"1981-03-09",16.1
"1981-03-10",11.8
"1981-03-11",12.2
"1981-03-12",0
"1981-03-13",0
"1981-03-14",NA
"1981-03-15",10.6
"1981-03-16",11.7
```

The dataframe is similar to yours: instead of every 10 minutes records, you have daily temperatures with some record NAs and 0s.

Here the working example. With a few tweaks you can adapt it to your case.

```
daily_min_temperatures <- read.csv("daily-min-temperatures.txt") #load sample dataframe
daily_min_temperatures$Date <- as.Date(daily_min_temperatures$Date) #format Date field

str(daily_min_temperatures) #view the structure of the loaded dataframe
summary(daily_min_temperatures) #view the summary of the loaded dataframe

library(tidyverse) #load the tidyverse library to get some nice to have tools :)
#part 1: average temp for full dataframe
na.omit(daily_min_temperatures) %>% #remove the NAs entries from the dataframe with the na.omit statement
filter(Temp != 0) %>% #remove the 0s entries from the dataframe with the filter statement
summarise(mean = mean(Temp)) #calculate the Temp mean

#part 2: average temp for monthly dataframe
na.omit(daily_min_temperatures) %>% #remove the NAs entries from the dataframe with the na.omit statement
filter(Temp != 0) %>% #remove the 0s entries from the dataframe with the filter statement
group_by(Grouped_Date = format(Date, format="%m/%Y")) %>% #Group by month year
summarise(mean = mean(Temp)) #calculate the Temp mean for each group
```